# CSS - Change Margin of a Menu's Items..?

Tags: css, menu, padding, margin, menuitem

I'm quite new to CSS but currently need it to solve an issue with a website builder.

I have a horizontal menu (hmenu) on my page, which can also contain submenu items. However, these are spaced far apart (20px margin top and bottom).

[MenuItem-Sub Margin Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y18zP.png)

[MenuItem-Sub Margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCmWD.png)

[MenuItem Padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYcmC.png)

Now, this is the output from Chrome's source code display...
Specifically... the hmenu and the (sub-)menu items.

As the website builder does not offer an option to set the margin per submenu item, I need to solve this with custom CSS.

Can someone help me and tell me how to change the margin of the submenu items, as well as the padding of the main menu items?

I'm inexperienced in CSS and only doing this out of necessity. I have absolutely no idea where to start with this.

Comment: You need to edit your question to improve it. Specifically, you need to **copy and paste** the relevant code into your question. Screen shots of code are not acceptable. Also, review the article [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There is no "Code"
Since the Website is constructed via a Website-Kit Editor.
I can only paste in custom CSS and HTML Code, into predefined fields.

Like Wordpress Elementor.. but with no direct HTML/CSS editing possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We need the **generated** code which is sent to the browser. You can copy text from Chrome’s code display.